# Forces that affect a car in a circular motion

Tags: forces, orbital-motion

In a circular motion, with an angular speed ω, mass m and radius r. The resulting force affecting an object(let's say a car) can be calculated with this formula:
$$F_{res} = m \cdot \omega^{2} \cdot r$$
Since this is only the resulting force, other forces are at work too.
If the object is a car, what are those other forces?

Comment: Mostly static friction between the tracks and the wheels

Comment: Also, be careful: the resulting force is not an interaction. The “other forces” you mention are actually the only forces acting on the car. That expression for the centripetal force is just their sum, and is not a model for any of the interactions that are happening.

Comment: Yeah, good point, the resulting force is just that, a resulting force, not an actual force in itself.

Comment: How exactly would the static friction between the tracks and the wheels affect it? Would there be other forces in play aswell?

Comment: As in, how would I be able to visualize it? Or a formula or something

Comment: Btw isn't the reulsting force = centri petal force?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m going to answer the question as comments should not be a medium for discussion.

The main idea here is understanding the process of making a car turn. How’s that done?

A simplified view is that the axle of the front wheels is rotated by some angle $\theta$ with respect to the back wheels. However, the wheels keep rolling on the floor, making the car turn into that new direction that the front wheels are pointing.

So, kinematically, our model makes sense. Now we need to try and identify any forces that might be acting on the car.

Let’s simplify our problem a bit by assuming that our $\theta$ is small. If the distance between the wheel axles is $L$, then the radius of the trajectory is approximately $R\approx L/\theta$. If the car has mass $m$ and moves with constant speed $v$, then, as you’ve said, there must be a resultant radial inward pointing force

$$F=m\frac{v^2}{R}=\frac{mv^2}{L}\theta.$$

But where does this come from? Well, neglecting drag, the only forces that can act on the plane of motion are friction forces between the wheels and the track. Since the car doesn’t change speed, these forces have to act on each wheel perpendicular to their velocity. The wheels don’t slip, either, so this force has to be static friction.

Considering the position of the car as the midpoint of the line joining the axles, we can say each of them forms an angle $\theta/2$ with the circle radius. We now suppose that each wheel has a friction force of magnitude $f$ acting on it. As such, the radial component of the resultant force is

$$4 f\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\approx4f. $$

Equaling this to $F$, we write an approximate expression for this friction force in terms of the small angle $\theta$,

$$f=\frac{mv^2}{4L}\theta.$$

This is the friction acting between each wheel and the track, answering your question.

We can go a step further and estimate the maximum angle the wheels can turn before the car starts to slip. Each wheel supports a weight $mg/4$, and so if the coefficient of friction is $\mu$, then

$$f= \frac{mv^2}{4L}\theta\leq \frac{\mu mg}{4}$$
$$\theta\leq\frac{\mu gL}{v^2}.$$

Remember that this is valid for small $\theta$, i.e. $\mu gL\ll v^2$.

Comment: Toronto had an elevated highway with a descending, clockwise, decreasing radius, helical off-ramp.  The inward centripetal force was often supplied by the ramp wall applied to the left-hand side body panels, and on rare occasions the driver's left elbow contributed...

Comment: Right. But I just wanted to illustrate the problem with a very simple model.